# Verb Dictionary form+ よう

Tags: grammar

「お断りの連絡でしたら引き受けます。
あんまり無茶するようでしたらお注射の出番ですからねっ」

Why is よう after the dictionary form of the verb?

Comment: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/226613/m0u/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is 連体形 not 終止形 (dictionary form), but in modern Japanese, verbs' 連体形 and 終止形 are always same.

> あんまり無茶する**よう**でしたらお注射の出番ですからねっ
>
> If **it seems that** you don't behave yourself at all, you know, it will be time for an injection!

Comment: What about だ? That would have fairly complex rules for its 連体形, wouldn't it? (Though the ordinary would be である and な.)

Comment: @Nothingatall The answer says "verbs' 連体形 and 終止形", not *all* 連体形 and 終止形.

Comment: So 連体形 form would be

食者を食べるひと

While 終止形 form would be

人が食者を食べる

The only difference is if it modifies a name or if it is a sentence ending verb.
Am i right?

Comment: @Nothingatall 形容動詞 and some 助動詞 have a different 連体形 from its 終止形.

Comment: @Splikie What is 食者? Oh, is it 食べ物 or 食物? If my guess is right, you are right. 体言 basically means noun, and 連体形 literally means a form to connect to 体言. So, it comes just before 体言.

Comment: Yeah thanks, It was past midnight and forgot how to write it.